# box2d spatial type

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I'm storing data that defines a box. I created a column by adding it to my table as follows:

```
SELECT addgeometrycolumn('grid', 'grid_geometry', 32650, 'GEOMETRY', 2);
```

I then insert my data in using the following:

```
INSERT INTO grid(boundary_id, parameter, grid_geometry, date_created) VALUES (1, 1000, st_setsrid(box2d(st_collect(st_makepoint(123, 123) , st_makepoint(123, 123))), 32650), 12345);
```

I then use this to do a bunch of st_intersects() to figure out which trajectories of mine intersect with a specific box. What I have noticed is that when I created lots of these boxes my intersect calculations begun to take a very long time. In addition, my mapping program called qgis, which I help to visualize what I'm doing, is complaining that the table where these boxes are found doesn't have an entry in geometry_columns (There isn't entry in geometry_columns!).

I have created a spatial index on the grid_geometry column. The warning in qgis and the performance degradation as I increase the number of boxes has made me question whether I'm storing my box data correctly.

Thoughts?

Here are the details for the grid table:
[image]

Here is the sql query I'm using:

```
SELECT id
FROM grid
WHERE
  st_intersects(
      (SELECT st_endpoint(trajectory_geometry)
       FROM trajectory
       WHERE id = 2048), grid.grid_geometry) AND parameter = 1500;
```

And finally, here is the results of EXPLAIN ANALYZE of the above query:
[image]

Comment: Try using ST_MakeBox2D(ST_MakePoint(x,y), ST_MakePoint(x1,y1)). ST_Collect is pointless in this scenario as you only have two points anyway.

Comment: Did you put a proper index on it? Show the table definition + indices. Also the sample query with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`.

Comment: I have updated the original question with more details.

Comment: Have you run a `VACUUM ANALYZE` on the table after adding more data?

Comment: Did you do the EXPLAIN, did you do the Vacuum?

Also how many features are we talking about and how much memory are you giving to Postgresql? Could be that you are paging to disk and that would slow things down considerably

Comment: I have 1,565,214 entries in grid and 23,707 entries in trajectory. For each trajectory I'm trying to find which grid it starts and ends in. I'm running postgresql on macbook pro installed via homebrew. I modified the postgresql.config file located at /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.3.5_1/share/postgresql with the following: shared_buffers = 4096MB, work_mem=100MB. The rest I've left as default. I'm using this DB for my own research so no one else is going to be connecting and using it except me. Maybe I should change other settings in the config file to speed things up?

Comment: I've run VACUUM ANALYZE with no visible results.

Comment: I ran some tests where I only loaded the exact grids I needed into my grid table and then ran my jobs. When doing so things performed much faster. In other words when my grid table has few rows my queries run faster. This makes sense to some extent but I thought that by indexing the columns on which I am doing my intersects would speed things up. I must be doing something wrong.